# AJAX not sending user-input from a form to PHP script

Tags: php, ajax, forms, user-input

I've been trying to learn basic AJAX and Javascript by following various tutorials and examples online, but I've hit a wall. I'm trying to write a simple script to take user-input from a form using AJAX and submit it to a PHP script, which then just echos the input.

All I can really tell is that whatever is being entered is not going through, but I'm not at the point yet where I can say why. I've tried with both POST and GET, and with various dataTypes, with the same result. I'm certain that I'm doing something wrong or misunderstanding something, but I'm not sure what.

**HTML/ AJAX**

```
<form id="my_form">
    word <input type ="text" id="word1"/><br/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#my_form").on(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var verb = $("word1").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "testrun.php",
            data: "verb",
            type: "POST",
        });        
    });
});
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['verb'])){
   $x= $_POST['verb'];
   echo $x;
}else { 
   echo "not working";
}
```

EDIT: I've tried a few of the suggestions thus far, copying and pasting them directly, and none of them have actually done anything that I can see. I think I'm starting to understand a bit more about how AJAX should work, based on the responses, but it's still not reaching the PHP for some reason. I've tried both with the AJAX/HTML in a separate file that calls to the testrun.php script and with putting everything into the testrun.php file and basically having it call itself with the AJAX, but neither approach has achieved anything.

If the AJAX that I've gotten from the responses is fine, then am I misunderstanding something in how the PHP should be set up in order to actually receive the POST data? I'm still rather lost.

Comment: you miss to give the `#` sign in `var verb = $ ("word1").val();`

Comment: @Anant: great friend, u r supporting others... salute my friend.

Comment: @Anant: thumbs up bro

Comment: @Anant I've tried running the code that I've been given here, but it's not giving me any different results.

Comment: @Anant Okay, I see it now. I was misunderstanding something. Your answer was correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Three changes:-**

1.`var verb = $ ("word1").val();` need to be  `var verb = $ ("#word1").val();`because its id (`word1`)

2.`data: "verb",` needs to be  `data: {"verb":verb},`

3.form submission need to be correct so code given below (missing `submit`):-

Correct code:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#my_form").on('submit',function(e){ // check here you have one missing `submit`
        e.preventDefault();
        var verb = $("#word1").val(); // remove space between `$` and `(`
        $.ajax({
          url: "testrun.php",
          data: {"verb":verb},
          type: "POST",
        });
   });
});
```

Comment: u r the ist who give this answer.... earn my vote bro. it will also resolve with: `data: "verb="+verb,` as i suggest.

Comment: `var verb = $ ("#word1").val();` is it work perfectly? i think  here `$ ("#word1")` is a gap btn the `$` and `(`.

Comment: just so you know, there was no missing `)`. It was where it needs to be, line 12 after `}`

Answer (score 2):

You can not send data as `data: "verb",` in ajax. you need to send your data in params.

Second, you can not get the value of `word1` input as `$("word1").val();` you need to use `#` for get input by IDs.

**Example:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#my_form" ).submit(function( e ) { //CHANGED using submit event.
        e.preventDefault();
        var verb = $("#word1").val(); //CHANGED
        $.ajax({
        url: "testrun.php",
        data: "verb="+verb, //CHANGED
        type: "POST",
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: on change needed here:-  `$("#my_form").on(function(e){`  it will not submit form. just a suggestion

Answer (score 1):

you miss to give the `#` sign in `var verb = $("word1").val();`

and use a variable just as a variable to the `data` like `data: {"your_var_name" : verb}`

Comment: ONE MORE THING NEED TO CHANGE

Answer (score 1):

1. You forgot `#` foe id selector of `word1`.
2. `.on()` needs event to bind to. In your case of form submit, it's `submit`
3. Data should be passed as object. In your case, you will be able to access it with `$_POST['verb']`

   ```
   $(document).ready(function ()
   {
       $("#my_form").on('submit', function (e)
       {
           e.preventDefault();
           var verb = $("#word1").val();
           $.ajax({
               url: "testrun.php",
               data: {verb: verb},
               type: "POST"
           });
       });
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this:

```
var verb = $("#word1").val();  //Don't forget to add #
$.ajax({
    url: "testrun.php",
    data: {"verb":verb},
    type: "POST",
});
```

`verb` is a variable, no need to put in between quotation!

The correct answer is
[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35570170/ajax-not-sending-user-input-from-form-to-php-script/35570213#35570213) by [Anant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4248328/anant)

Comment: kermani still lot of thing need to change in OP's code. Please check my answer

Comment: @Anant Yes I saw your answer, and even up voted for it. Your answer is correct. Thanks

Comment: @Anant Man you are great, I opened your profile you answered good questions. I up-voted for some of your answers. I believe that correct things should be in Stackoverflow. I hope that help the community

Comment: @Anant Thanks, I did not know. but those answers were great and needed to get point and up-vote

Answer (score 0):

**Try this** ...

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "testrun.php",
  data: "paramname=value",  // access in php $_POST['paramname']
  success: function(data){
    // if page request is success
  },
  error: function(data){
    // if page request failes
  }
});
```